# How to find distinct ngrams in scala?

Tags: scala, nlp, apache-spark-mllib, n-gram

I have a email address and i wanted to find the count of distinct ngram on the email_alias.Lets say xyz at gmail.com is the email.

email_alias is xyz .

so it has to give the count of distinct ngram is 2 if by n here is 2

```
def apply(in1:String,in2:Int):List[(Array[String], Int)] = {
   val email_alias = in1.split("@").toList
   val email_tokens = email_alias(0).split("") 
   val gram=email_tokens.sliding(in2).toList
   val fin=gram.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList
   return fin
}


val str="xyzxyz@gmail.com"
apply(str,2)
```

output is as below .

```
res121: List[(Array[String], Int)] = List((Array(z, x),1), (Array(x, y),1), (Array(y, z),1), (Array(x, y),1), (Array(y, z),1))
```

Comment: What problem you have? Show what code you have.

Comment: Added in the question now and this does not work as expected.It returns List of values.However i need distinct ngrams single output.

Comment: You can edit it in your question. It will be easier to read.

Comment: Now explain what problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
def ngram(emailAddress: String, groupCount: Int): List[(String, Int)] =
  emailAddress
    .takeWhile(_ != '@')
    .sliding(groupCount)
    .toList
    .groupBy(identity)
    .mapValues(_.length)
    .toList
```

I think each step is self-explanatory, but add a comment if you need a more detailed explanation.

---

The specific value you ask for in the comments can be computed as follows:

```
def ngramRatio(emailAddress: String, groupCount: Int): Float = {
  val prefix = emailAddress.takeWhile(_ != '@')
  val distinct = prefix.sliding(groupCount).toList.distinct.length

  distinct.toFloat / (prefix.length - groupCount + 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am actually trying to find the 

distinct_ngram/Total_Ngram in an email.

One single integer should be for an email_id.So incase of the email  "xyzxyz@gmail.com" output should be 


distinct_ngram/Total_Ngram
distinct_ngram =3
Total_Ngram=5
out=0.6

Answer (score 0):

First problem is your return type.

You have `List[(Array[String], Int)]` which mean list of tuples which first element is array of string. So you n-gram represented as array of string on length 1.

I suggest you to change it to `Seq[(String, Int)]`, so you n-grams represented by string.

Then you have combine arrays of string to string. You can achieve it with `mkString` method.

Final code is:

```
  def apply(in1: String, in2: Int): Seq[(String, Int)] = {
    val email_alias = in1.split("@").toList
    val email_tokens = email_alias(0).split("")
    val gram = email_tokens.sliding(in2).toList.map(_.mkString)
    val fin = gram.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList
    return fin
  }


  val str = "xyzxyz@gmail.com"
  println(apply(str, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am actually trying to find the distinct_ngram/Total_Ngram in an email.One single integer should be for an email_id.

Comment: So incase of the email "xyzxyz@gmail.com" output should be distinct_ngram/Total_Ngram distinct_ngram =3 Total_Ngram=5 out=0.6

Comment: To get total sum all values in result or simply subtract n-gram length from username length.